# Why do I get an incorrect Voronoi diagram?

Tags: d3.js, voronoi

I'm trying to generate a Voronoi diagram for a set of latitude/longitude points.

```
var points = [["-87.63374","41.878723"],["-87.680622","41.829353"],["-87.631739","41.8768"],["-87.626149","41.884431"]] ;
var boundingRegion = d3.geom.polygon([
    [-88, 41.7],
    [-88, 42.3],
    [-87.5, 42.3],
    [-87.5, 41.7]
    ]);

var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi(points).map(function(cell) {
    return boundingRegion.clip(cell);
});

document.write("<pre>"+JSON.stringify(voronoi, null, ' ')+"</pre>");​
```

I have a JSFiddle for that basic example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZzjpC/2/

I'm putting in 4 points and clipping them by using a simple rectangle.

The points are such that I should see at least one clipped vertex for each of the resulting Voronoi regions... the first one alone does not meet that.

When you plot them on a Google Map, the polygons intersect and are in total disarray.

If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/ZzjpC/3/, where the last point has been removed, everything looks fine.

So here's my question: is there something wrong with my set of points that is causing the Voronoi diagram generation to fail? Or is this a D3 bug and I should be telling those folks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with the fact that my Voronoi sites (`points`) were arrays of strings instead of floats was the cause of the issue. My guess is that there was an addition taking place somewhere that was executed as a string concatenation instead and that broke things.

Converting the `points` to floats instead of strings fixed the problem.